# Home page in Website only displaying background color and footer

Tags: wordpress, safari, mobile-safari

This is my first time asking a question here. I have a website I built using Underscores for a WordPress Theme. The Home Page is not displaying in Safari on my MacBook or on iPhones I've tested it on. It displays just fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. When I look at the inspector I don't see anything that indicates what is happening. If anyone would please look at karialbro.com and let me know what I'm missing I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Element with the ID "hero" doesnt have any height or width specifications

```
<div class="start-grid" id="hero" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://karialbro.com/wp-content/themes/karialbrocoach/images/BenchQuote.jpg&quot;);">
```

Set the height and width. This will vary from device to device, therefore use JavaScript to set this elements width and height based on the innerWidth and innerHeight

**Chrome, Firefox**
These browsers use the web-kit engine and works without height and width spec

However other browsers like Microsoft Edge does not
It worked for me in Chrome also, but not in Microsoft Edge, which indicates your problem is with no height or width specifications as this is a known problem for IE and chances are its the reason your not getting a background in your browser too

Comment: I have 100vw and 100vh respectively assigned to #hero. Not sure why it's not showing in your browser.

Comment: The website is running on a SSL Socket (HTTPS) but the backgrounds have a URL with a HTTP protocol which is insecured, make sure the backgrounds come from an HTTPS URL also

Comment: See following error

Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure prefetch resource '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):8 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://karialbro.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure prefetch resource 'http://karialbro.com/wp-content/themes/karialbrocoach/images/Desk.jpg'. This request has been blocked;

Comment: I have changed them all to "https" and it's still not rendering.

Comment: Have you tried the following:
-webkit-height: 5.2vh;
-moz-height: 5.2vh;
-ms-height: 5.2vh;
-o-height: 5.2vh;
height: 41px;  /* The Fallback */

If that doesnt resolve it, im not sure what it could be, but its 4am in the Uk and going to call it a night

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The way I wrote out the animations for #hero kept the entire div in 0 opacity. Once I rearranged the animation/transitions in my stylesheet it worked. Thanks for the help!